# Вывести картинки из одного поля

Tags: php, mysql

В базе mysql в одном поле `pic` есть вот такие данные:

```
5956390763.jpg,5956390651.jpg,5956391443.jpg,5956391590.jpg
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вытащить их, чтобы в итоге были представлены в виде:

```
<img src="5956390763.jpg"/>
<img src="5956390651.jpg"/>
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$imagesString  = "5956390763.jpg,5956390651.jpg,5956391443.jpg,5956391590.jpg";
$images = explode(",", $imagesString);

foreach ($images as $imageName)
    printf("<img src=\"%s\"/>\n", $imageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pic  = "5956390763.jpg,5956390651.jpg";
$img= explode(",", $pic);
echo $img[0];
echo $img[1];
```